# Get rid of hover effect on dropdown-list

Tags: c#, css, dropdownlistfor

I got a dropdownlist with different colors in my MVC-project:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BehanlingsColour, new SelectList(
                  new List<Object>{ 
                       new { value = "#7fe553" , text = "Red" },
                       new { value = "#295616" , text = "Yellow" },
                       new { value = "#165651" , text = "Green"},
```

The point of this list is for the user to pick a color.
The problem is that blue hover-effect i get when hovering over the colors...Is there a way to get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot style the hover properties of options with CSS. Your workaround is to fake the drop-down with a different markup structure and wire-up the interactive effect with javascripts. There are many front-end frameworks that can help you with this. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is one of the most widely-used.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for answering! 
I was thinking that maybe i could fake it by having a hover-effect changing the background-color to whatever color im hovering over...Cant get it to work though..